# Howto tell maven to use timestamp when starting dependency:copy-dependencies goal?

Tags: dependencies, maven, copy

I need to create an update site with SNAPSHOT-jars. I want to hold the old jars, so I need to have a unique name for every iteration of a snapshot lib, which means I need the timestamp.

First I get all jars from maven repositories by using a pom.xml including all jars as dependencies. After that I call mvn dependency:copy-dependencies .

The thing is, maven uses the name project-SNAPSHOT.jar instead of project-{timestamp}.jar.
Is their a way to configure the dependency plugin?

thanks in advance

Hannes

Answer (score 0):

From this [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html), it looks like this can be achieved if you were to do `dependency:copy` instead of `dependency:copy-dependencies`. In this case, for each `artifactItem` you can specify a `destFileName` which can be in the format you want.